# How i can create the function for the countdown in React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My skills in react native is basic, i want to create a basic countdown,  when i click play the countdown start, like this example:

[image]

**My Code:**

```
render() {
return (

<Grid>
<Row>

<Col style={styles.col_exercise}>
<Image source={require('../../assets/images/done.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.icon_videoexercise} />
<Text style={styles.titlecol_exercise}>Done</Text>
</Col>

<Col style={styles.col_exercise}>
<View style={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#f39c12', borderRadius: 50, height: 100, width: 100,alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center'}}>
<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#000'}}>
00:30
</Text>
</View>
</Col>

<Col style={styles.col_exercise}>
<Image source={require('../../assets/images/play.png')} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.icon_videoexercise} />
<Text style={styles.titlecol_exercise}>Play</Text>
</Col>

</Row>

</Grid>
);
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What **specific** problem are you stuck with at the moment?

Comment: How i can create the function for the countdown..

Comment: Edit your question to say that, and then post the relevant code you've written for doing that thus far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { timer: 30 };
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.clockCall = setInterval(() => {
   this.decrementClock();
 }, 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
 clearInterval(this.clockCall);
}

decrementClock = () => {      
 this.setState((prevstate) => ({ timer: prevstate.timer-1 }));
};
```

You can create a countdown with `setInterval`. Every second `this.decrementClock()` will be called after the component mounts.
You will want to render `this.state.timer` in your render method.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { timer: 30 };
}

startTimer = () => {
 this.clockCall = setInterval(() => {
  this.decrementClock();
 }, 1000);
}

decrementClock = () => {  
 if(this.state.timer === 0) clearInterval(this.clockCall)
 this.setState((prevstate) => ({ timer: prevstate.timer-1 }));
};

componentWillUnmount() {
 clearInterval(this.clockCall);
}
```

In render add the button with `Onpress` event listener.

```
<button Onpress={this.startTimer}> Play </button>

<Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#000'}}>
 {this.state.timer === 0 ? 'Times Up!' : {this.state.timer} }
</Text>
```

Comment: How ia can integrate it with play button? with Onpress?

Comment: i test it but not working. i need to change this line right? <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color: '#000'}}> 00:30 </Text>

Comment: that should not be 00:30 , it needs to be `{this.state.timer}`

Comment: Is working when i replace the onClick with Onpress, but how i can stop the timer when is finish and prevent -1,-2-3...

Comment: ok thank you, how i can pause it ? because when i click one more makes the countdown very fast

Comment: i think have answered a lot of your questions, that being said If i solved your initial problem please accept the answer, if you are having trouble with this app consider opening up a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: ok thank you, just im waiting the final code to accept it , don't worry xD, i change this code: {this.state.timer === 0 ? 'Times Up!' : {this.state.timer} } but i get this error: this is . a reserved word.

Comment: { this.state.timer === 0 ? 'Times Up!' : (this.state.timer) }

Comment: how can I prevent negative numbers, because it does not stop at times up, it continues -1, -2, -3 ..etc

Comment: you can help to complete it please?

Answer (score 2):

To prevent negative numbers try this:

```
decrementClock = () => {  
  this.setState((prevstate) => ({ 
    timer: prevstate.timer-1 
  }), () => {
    if(this.state.timer === 0) {
      clearInterval(this.clockCall)
    }
  })
}
```